# From chemfig to .mol file

Tags: diagrams, chemfig, chemistry, mol2chemfig

Yes, I know [this package](https://ctan.org/pkg/mol2chemfig) can generate structure from .mol and SMILES files. I'd like to know: is it possible to follow the reverse path, i.e. once the structure has been drawn with chemfig, generate the .mol file and/or the SMILES?